# Vue.js: Re-bind to element if it's removed from the DOM

Tags: javascript, vue.js

**[jsBin available here](http://jsbin.com/qarekigopo/edit?html,js,output)**

My current scenario is that I am building a Vue.js-based plugin for the [TinyMCE Editor](http://tinymce.com).

The plugin allows me to configure certain elements in the editor reactively, before saving them (which would `$destroy()` the instance, and keep the element's rendered HTML in the editor in a no-longer-modifiable state).

There are several situations while editing where a particular element is replaced in the content (e.g. switching to "View source" and back). This causes me to lose the connection between `vm` and the HTML Element.

**Description of the problem:**

Here is a [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/qarekigopo/edit?html,js,output) with a depiction of the problem. When clicking on **Replace Element**, one of the elements that is bound to Vue is replaced with a clone of itself. At this moment, it stops being bound to the data.

What can I do (if anything) in this situation to restore the bindings?

I tried asking in the [Gitter channel](https://gitter.im/vuejs/vue), and also looking at the Vue source code, but I did not find anything. I also tried doing:

```
var vueConfig = { /* ... */ };
vm = new Vue(vueConfig);

onExternalReplacement = function() {
  vm.$destroy();
  vm = new Vue(vueConfig);
}
```

But since the cloned element does not have any of the original Vue directives (e.g. `:style`), it doesn't really help at all.

Thank you!

Comment: the actual problem is vue *binds* data to DOM nodes. when you replace element, you destroy the *vue bindings*. I can only suggest you to replace only html nodes instead of vue-bind nodes. 
if that's not an option, clarify your use case. its possible that there is a more idiomatic way to solve it.